# При запуске программы ничего не происходит

Tags: python, python-3.x, sublime-text-3

Решил попробовать написать простого бота в Telegram, но при  попытке запуска программы и вывода текста встретил такую проблему:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При повторной попытке запуска появляется следующее:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
 import requests
 import misc

token = misc.token

URL = 'https://api.telegram.org' + token + '/'
# https://api.telegram.org/bot565935674:AAHuuSgWyEyeg-DLkPzNifK1i_PqoORKu1c/getupdates


def get_updates():
    url + URL + getupdates
    print(url)
#   r = requests.get(url)

def main():
    get_updates

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Есть решения проблемы, которые могут помочь?

Comment: В начале документа
#coding: UTF-8

Comment: Чтобы повысить вероятность того, что Вам помогут, пожалуйста, вставьте в вопрос Ваш код, а не только скриншот. ([**Аргументы**](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4692/199934)). Спасибо.

Comment: @Кирилл, сейчас это [**не обязательно**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14083123/5951529). Спасибо.

Comment: `get_updates()`

Comment: Возможно забыл добавить слеш после именования адреса сервера
URL = 'https://api.telegram.org/' + token

Comment: Владимир Аршулик, установите [**Sublime Anaconda**](http://damnwidget.github.io/anaconda/) → посмотрите, какие ошибки высвечиваются. У меня [**вот так**](https://i.imgur.com/VKqNhPW.png) получается. Что за модуль `misc`, откуда переменные `url` и `getupdates`? Спасибо.

Comment: Sublime очень не плохой редактор, и ОООЧЕНЬ универсальный. В этом его преимущества и недостатки (так сказать два в одном). На правах IMHO: для кодописания в Python поставьте Anaconda3 и используйте ее Spider или как еще один бесплатный но очень толковый вариант используйте PyCharm Community

Comment: @OleLukøje, вообще никак не связано с вопросом. Если есть проблемы с пониманием Python, то просто переход на другой редактор или IDE никак не поможет.

Answer (score 1):

Как минимум потеряли слеш в конце адреса, и НЕ записываете значение в переменную url

```
import requests
import misc

token = misc.token

URL = 'https://api.telegram.org/' + token + '/'
# https://api.telegram.org/bot565935674:AAHuuSgWyEyeg-DLkPzNifK1i_PqoORKu1c/getupdates


def get_updates():
    return requests.get(URL + 'getupdates')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(get_updates())
```